# Edit non-readable code from a ruby "*.RB" file extension that includes part of redeable code

Tags: ruby

I have a .RB file with 18.000 lines of code.
I open it up with a editor like Notepad++, or Komodo IDE and get the same results.

At the begining of the file starts from line 1 to 36 with blocks of code that looks like this:

```
   H   x      
   [   x      
   v   x      
   ‰   x      
   œ   x
```

Then from line 36 to 465 there is readable code like this:

```
On
On$   Temperature
Sound
Music / ambience   Fahrenheit
Off
Off   Celsius
Fahrenheit   Full Screen   Click to change options
```

Then from line 465 to 18.000 ther is again non-redable code like this:

```
Eý,›öŸùg›ÅÍ¼_Éü9r-ÔÅœ.²²YªÑ)þ<Oä\à    mÒ<_D…nG|ä³ƒÆŸ0òôŒ2_³ºÈ‡bdîå•‚,¶
µ6³©. ÿ~òä½¼"¢¼šec,¯¦GÔO±±xrÎFÆ¨ò2'È¿ÊÇ¦
9ßšrgb\Œ9X3ê‘gMt¢ïŒÚ¾w6«›@žçYTO¥BÊ„W¥^ô®Xô%áŸÇ™ÑÜñhÙÃÇ‘KÿÄO¹7²±bŒ¬7=+æO{Ž»8fá7íh‚ÜŽB0¿dÆ—î‹É7ñ˜…        O:WªiÄeëøÖK
Ü2«¼Tùk+¤Ë×l,—Xš³ðIS+?œD!»kœl+YáçžxúàÓæ”Ç7ýü¹ÔÇ,|ÔjDÖˆðB"ükF˜ó%3b'ËÅæ+C¿éŽYøÍæ*ØîïâfÈWC¸2‰p*¾¿~[ùãkeœ¯0Ç,”[9é¢aûAÜ4œas¿‘=6;?=J1ë
#÷™Ì»IuÌÂäÕ²‘fv
```

Any ideas of how to decrypth or decode the code after line 465?
Best regards

Comment: *"from line 36 to 465 there is readable code"* - does that look like Ruby to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that this file is a Ruby file. There are several other applications that use the `.rb` file extension. Why do you think that it may be a Ruby file?

Perhaps it is a REAL Basic file: http://filext.com/file-extension/RB ?

Comment: @user3251927: And was it REAL Basic?

Comment: Yes it was.
This code was made by a software called "Xojo" a.k.a "Real Software Inc".

But couse the similarity of the extensions ".rb" with ruby, they have moved on to ".rpb", so I needed to download an old version of the actual version called "RealBasic 5.5 2004" couse on the previous verions they can't reade them anymore! Thanks a lot!